# Solve 3 simultaneous eqns to find the roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve: $24x^3+46x^2+9x-9=0$ and $a_1=2a_2$

$a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the three roots of the polynomial
$$a_1+a_2+a_3=-\frac{23}{12}...(I)$$

$$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1=\frac{9}{24}...(II)$$

$$a_1a_2a_3=\frac{9}{4}...(III)$$

substituting  $a_1=2a_2$ in (I), (II), (III) I got

$$3a_2+a_3=-\frac{23}{12} ... (A)$$

$$a_2^2\cdot a_3=\frac{9}{8} ...(B)$$ $$2a_2^2+3a_2\cdot a_3=\frac{9}{24}...(C)$$

Experiencing a little mental/ math fog, can you tell me how do I solve for $a_1, a_3, a_3 $?

Comment: Are $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$ roots of given cubic equation?

Comment: yes they are @choco_addicted,

Comment: **Hint:** Use $A$ to substitute for $a_3$ in $C$, you get a quadratic in $a_1$.  Now check which root(s) work.

Comment: $III$ and $B$ are wrong: the producto of the roots is $9/24$

Answer (score 1):

From (A) : $\quad a_3=-\frac{23}{12}-3a_2$

Substituing $a_3$ in (C) : $\quad 2a_2^2+3a_2(-\frac{23}{12}-3a_2)=\frac{9}{24}$

Solving this quadratic equation for $a_2$ gives two values $\quad -\frac{3}{4}\quad$ and $\quad -\frac{1}{14}\quad$

Testing both in putting them into the cubic equation shows that $\quad -\frac{1}{14}\quad$ is not a root and that $\quad a_2=-\frac{3}{4}\quad$ is a root.

$a_1=2a_2=-\frac{3}{2}$

Bringing back the value of $a_2$ into (A) gives $a_3=\frac{1}{3}$.